# Do any versions of The Avengers/Stark Tower have a flying defense robot similar to this one?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, robots, lego

For Christmas, I received [this LEGO set of the Avengers Tower](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NHQFIRE).

[image: LEGO Avengers Tower]

It comes with some sort of flying robot defense-system that launches from the very top of the tower.

[image: Drone close-up]

The set is mostly based off *Avengers: Age of Ultron* and the robot is really the only part of the set that seems unrelated to that film.

Have any other versions of The Avengers/Stark Tower (from comics, cartoons, etc.) featured a robot similar to the set's?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## "Hidden drone" in Stark Tower

Apparently, this is a "hidden drone" according to the [Toys R Us web site](http://t.toysrus.com/product/index.jsp?productId=45304726):

[image]

> Send the Iron Man mini figure to the JARVIS control room to activate the **hidden drone**, which features a stud shooter that will prevent the Ultron Mark 1 mini figure from getting away.

## Appearances in media: none

There do not appear to be any appearances of this specific hidden drone in Stark Tower in comic books, nor does it appear in any MCU films or television series.

The drone seems to have been created purely for this Lego set.

Comment: “The drone seems to have been created purely for this Lego set.” I bet Tony added it after the whole Ultron mess. Unfortunately I also bet it eventually turns into Ultron mark III.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the right armor, but Superior Iron Man used similar drones in that mini-series. Though they aren't really used offensively and are more meant to observe Los Angeles.